# What is the difference between Mysql temporary table and oracle temporary table

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g

What is the difference between MYSQL and ORACLE temporary table

Comment: One is in a MySQL database and the other is in an Oracle database...

Comment: @MT0 . . . And that's a pretty big difference (this is not sarcasm).

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle temporary table only data is temporary, table is permanent. Data will be wiil be visible until you fix transaction or end your session (depends of option you choose)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#BABDFGBD

> In MySQL, temporary tables are database objects that are visible only
>   to the current user session and are automatically dropped when the
>   user session ends.
>
> The definition of temporary tables in Oracle differs slightly from
>   MySQL, in that the temporary tables, once created, exist until they
>   are explicitly dropped and they are visible to all sessions with
>   appropriate privileges. However, the data in the temporary tables is
>   visible only to the user session that inserts the data into the table,
>   and the data may persist for the duration of a transaction or a user
>   session.